# Select records from inserted table for columns that are not null, and columns not null only if another column is Y

Tags: sql

We're selecting columns to export for our ERP/CRM synchronization. We're selecting records from our GoldMine CRM and inserting them into our bridge database. It works as a que and we import to the ERP at an interval. The records are selected from the inserted table with the code below. For state (STATERES) and  (C2.UCOUNTY) the values can be null if International is Y. How can I add that condition to the AND statement in the WHERE clause. The relevant code is listed below.
SQL SERVER 2008R

```
    SELECT FROM inserted i

    WHERE 1=1 
    ...
    AND C2.USTATERES IS NOT NULL--State Res, can be null, if International is Y
    AND C2.UCOUNTY IS NOT NULL—County, can be null, if International is Y
    ...

    SELECT FROM inserted i

    WHERE 1=1 
    ...
    AND C2.USTATERES IS NOT NULL OR International = 'Y'--State Res, can be null, if International is Y
    AND C2.UCOUNTY IS NOT NULL OR International = 'Y'—County, can be null, if International is Y
    ...
```

Comment: Is there a chance that your code could be simplified just a little for purposes of your question?

Comment: @HABO . . . If the question were ever to be answered, it would need to be simplified.

Comment: `AND (C2.USTATERES IS NOT NULL OR INTERNATIONAL = 'Y')` Don't forget the parens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading through your code, it appears that this is the relevant portion:

```
AND C2.USTATERES IS NOT NULL--State Res, can be null, if International is Y
AND C2.UCOUNTY IS NOT NULL--County, can be null, if International is Y
```

To get the result you are requesting, you just need to add an OR condition that will allow the condition to pass when International is Y:

```
AND (C2.USTATERES IS NOT NULL OR C2.UINTERNAT = 'Y')--State Res, can be null, if International is Y
AND (C2.UCOUNTY IS NOT NULL OR C2.UINTERNAT = 'Y')--County, can be null, if International is Y
```

This solution does assume that the International field exists in either your i or C2 table.

Comment: That's a much more simple solution that what I was thinking of